# Can I sync Evolution's notes with Ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution, sync

I am looking for a way to sync Evolution's notes with Ubuntu One or Google Docs. But I can find only three options on Notes section of Evolution.
On this Computer
CalDAV
On the Web <-- Can I use this way to keep Evolution on a folder of my Google Docs account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the CalDAV and ON the Web options for notes mean exactly. I think Evolution might store notes in the same format that calendar events are stored, and are thus storable on a CalDAV server. However, no, you cannot sync notes from Evolution on Ubuntu One currently, that I know of.